# ¿Por qué submitHandler, no responde, jquery validate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Tengo mi siguiente vista con un formulario para el inicio de sesion:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-clear">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="center sliding"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="pages navbar-fixed toolbar-fixed">
    <div data-page="login" class="page">
        <div class="page-content">
            <div class="nice-header header-fix-top small">
                <div class="logo">
                    <h1>login</h1>
                    <h2>login</h2>
                </div>
                <svg class="anim-svg" viewBox="0 0 629 63" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
                    <defs></defs>
                    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
                        <g id="Splash" sketch:type="MSArtboardGroup" transform="translate(-60.000000, -749.000000)" fill="#FFFFFF">
                            <g id="flaga" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup">
                                <path d="M60.7617187,750.025391 L375.435547,811.568359 L688.558594,749.867188 L60.7617187,750.025391 Z" id="Path-30" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="login-view-box mt-50">
                <div class="list login-form-box">
                    <form name="formIniciar" action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off" id="formIniciar" class="form nice-label">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label for="usuario"><span class="icon-man"></span></label>
                            <input type="text" id="usuario" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario">
                        </div>
                        <label class="error" for="usuario"></label>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label for="password"><span class="icon-lock"></span></label>
                            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña">
                        </div>
                        <label class="error" for="password"></label>
                         <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="input-submit">
                                <a href="#" class="button button-secondary button-fill iniciar">Ingresar</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

tengo el problema que al usar jquery validate no ingresa a submitHandler, si realiza la validación ya que si no ingreso usuario o contraseña me sale el mensaje de validate.

```
$('form[name=formIniciar]').validate({
        rules: {
            usuario: {
                required: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages:{
            usuario:{
                required: "Por favor ingrese usuario"
            },
            password:{
                required: "Por favor ingrese contraseña"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form, e) {
            console.log("ENVIO DEL FORMULARIO") //ESTO NO LO MUESTRA EN CONSOLA.
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

```js
$('form[name=formIniciar]').validate({
            rules: {
                usuario: {
                    required: true
                },
                password: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages:{
             usuario:{
              required: "Por favor ingrese usuario"
             },
             password:{
              required: "Por favor ingrese contraseña"
             }
            },
            submitHandler: function (form, e) {
             console.log("ENVIO DEL FORMULARIO") //ESTO NO LO MUESTRA EN CONSOLA.
             e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<div class="navbar navbar-clear">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="center sliding"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pages navbar-fixed toolbar-fixed">
        <div data-page="login" class="page">
            <div class="page-content">
                <div class="nice-header header-fix-top small">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <h1>login</h1>
                        <h2>login</h2>
                    </div>
                    <svg class="anim-svg" viewBox="0 0 629 63" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
                        <defs></defs>
                        <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
                            <g id="Splash" sketch:type="MSArtboardGroup" transform="translate(-60.000000, -749.000000)" fill="#FFFFFF">
                                <g id="flaga" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup">
                                    <path d="M60.7617187,750.025391 L375.435547,811.568359 L688.558594,749.867188 L60.7617187,750.025391 Z" id="Path-30" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="login-view-box mt-50">
                    <div class="list login-form-box">
                        <form name="formIniciar" action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off" id="formIniciar" class="form nice-label">
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <label for="usuario"><span class="icon-man"></span></label>
                                <input type="text" id="usuario" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario">
                            </div>
                            <label class="error" for="usuario"></label>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <label for="password"><span class="icon-lock"></span></label>
                                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña">
                            </div>
                            <label class="error" for="password"></label>
                             <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="input-submit">
                                    <a href="#" class="button button-secondary button-fill iniciar">Ingresar</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Lo raro es que tengo otras vistas con jquery validate y ahí si me funciona sin ningun problema.

Tengo una carpeta
`www` que contiene 2 archivos
`index.html` y `login.html`
y tengo otra vista en la ruta
vistas/consultas/consultas.html //la ruta `vistas` se encuentra dentro de la carpeta `www`
en este archivo consultas.html si me trabaja normal el jquery validate.

de antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola he estado mirando tu código y he podido llegar a la siguiente conclusión.

1. La etiqueta de ingreso(href) no tiene ningún evento asociado o al menos en el fragmento que has puesto

Si quieres que el formulario se envié, puedes añadir un botón de tipo **"submit"** o hacerlo por medio de javascript.

Si quieres hacerlo mediante Javascript simplemente tienes que asignar un evento a tu href(ingresar).

Ejemplo:

```
<a href="#" onclick="enviarForm();">Ingresar</a>
```

Entonces cuando se haga click en ingresar llamas a la funcion `enviarForm()` para enviar el formulario.

No me enrollo más y te dejo el  código, que funciona perfectamente con un par de cambios.

```js
$('form[name="formIniciar"]').validate({
        rules: {
            usuario: {
                required: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages:{
            usuario:{
                required: "Por favor ingrese usuario"
            },
            password:{
                required: "Por favor ingrese contraseña"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form, e) {
            console.log("ENVIO DEL FORMULARIO")
            /**
            
            Aqui puedes hacer un fecth() hacia tu api.
            fetch(urlApi)
            no olvides el e.preventDefault()
             */
            
            /*
              Por ahora lo enviamos tal cual como esta
              definido en el html.
            */
            form.submit()
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<div class="navbar navbar-clear">

  <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="center sliding"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="pages navbar-fixed toolbar-fixed">
    <div data-page="login" class="page">
        <div class="page-content">
            <div class="nice-header header-fix-top small">
                <div class="logo">
                    <h1>login</h1>
                    <h2>login</h2>
                </div>
                <svg class="anim-svg" viewBox="0 0 629 63" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
                    <defs></defs>
                    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
                        <g id="Splash" sketch:type="MSArtboardGroup" transform="translate(-60.000000, -749.000000)" fill="#FFFFFF">
                            <g id="flaga" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup">
                                <path d="M60.7617187,750.025391 L375.435547,811.568359 L688.558594,749.867188 L60.7617187,750.025391 Z" id="Path-30" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="login-view-box mt-50">
                <div class="list login-form-box">
                    <form name="formIniciar" action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off" id="formIniciar" class="form nice-label">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label for="usuario"><span class="icon-man"></span></label>
                            <input type="text" id="usuario" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario">
                        </div>
                        <label class="error" for="usuario"></label>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label for="password"><span class="icon-lock"></span></label>
                            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña">
                        </div>
                        <label class="error" for="password"></label>
                         <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="input-submit">
                               <!--El input type submit o mediante js-->
                              <button type="submit">Ingresar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Espero haberte ayudado y un saludo!!!